# How to get the code editor to automatically select a particular control

Tags: vb.net, controls, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2022

In VB, on a form's designer, I used to be able to double-click a control (say a button) and it would bring up the code with the middle dropdown box (towards top) automatically selecting the control (button) for me.  Now it just stays stuck at 'Formx' unless I manually change it to the control I'm working with (button).  I did not see a setting for this issue.  It's killing my productivity!

Thank you in advance.

VS/VB 2022 (64-bit, version 17.03)

Comment: I can confirm what MatSnow found, seems like a bug for me too. But RE `It's killing my productivity!`, how often do you find yourself needing to choose the clicked control manually over the course of a day? :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in VS 2022.
Created a test-project and got the same behavior with VS 2022 (17.0.4)
while it worked with VS 2019.

So it would be best to report the problem via Visual Studio Feedback:
Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem...

### **Edit**

Thanks to @djv for the additional tests and thus eliciting further details and also for opening a ticket!

One can now vote here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-functionality-with-Event-Handler/1618211

Comment: Looking more into this, there is additional related missing behavior. Make an event handler (for any WithEvents property, even if it is not a Control) and make an event handler for some event it has. When you click inside the event handler, 2019 shows the second and third dropdowns with `objectname`, `eventname`, and 2022 doesn't change at all. Both 2019 and 2022 update the dropdowns when clicking in methods to `Form1`, `methodname`.  I guess this is related.

Comment: Just created a ticket. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-functionality-with-Event-Handler/1618211

Comment: @djv Thanks, I've edited the answer, added the link and also upvoted the ticket.